# Python - apache - windows 7 - wamp

Tags: python, windows, apache

I tried millions of times to install python with apache on my windows 7 32 bit. But failed. Can anybody tell me the simplest way to get it work???

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to run a simple web app built in python, [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) is an Apache module that will enable the server to run python code as either a daemon or as embedded code.

Comment: I think mod_wsgi might be what he is trying to install. And daemon mode doesn't run on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Common problems with Apache/mod_wsgi installation, if that is what you are trying to install are:

1. Installing a mix of 32 and 64 bit binaries for Apache, Python and mod_wsgi.
2. Not installing Python for all users on the system.

Do either of those and Apache will not startup properly.

Since you don't say what exactly failed, it is hard to guess. Provide more information.